# What is Pinkfong's magic phrase?

Tags: pinkfong

My toddler son, like many young children these days, is obsessed with Baby Shark and the related media. We recently took him to [Baby Shark Live](https://babysharklive.com/), which featured Pinkfong, mascot of the company, as much as it did Baby Shark. Poking around a little, I've found there's an entire franchise built around that character, including cartoon shows and web animations. Anyhow, during the show, at one point, the audience was asked to help recite the "magic phrase" to help him with some task, which sounded something like "Foi foi Pinkfong", which much of the audience seemed familiar with. In another song/animation. I know there's something involving Pinkfong having a magic star, but I haven't found details.

Does Pinkfong have a single magic phrase? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The catchphrase is "[Hoi Poi Pinkfong"](https://open.spotify.com/track/6zuu9TbFgyrL0AclmTGNtb). He says it repeatedly in shows like Wonderstars

[image]

and on YouTube

Comment: For the record, I don't have a clue what this means in Korean. If anyone can assist, I'd appreciate it